# date time format in open office database

Tags: java, openoffice.org

What is the date format to use with open office database version 3.3

Upon trying the following query it is showing

> java.sql.SQLDataException: data exception: invalid datetime format

the query i used is

```
int status=stmt.executeUpdate("insert into \"Emp_Leave\" values(9876321,'8-9-11','9-9-11','pay','grant')");
```

here Emp_leave is the table in the database:

```
First column : EmpID ; Number
second column: StartDate:Date
Third column : LastDate : Date
Fourth column: Type:String
Fifth column : comments:String
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is an internal [HSQLDB] database, I think you'll need to specify '2011-09-09':

> A DATE literal starts and ends with ' (singlequote), the format is yyyy-mm-dd (see java.sql.Date)

(from [HSQLDB Insert reference](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch09.html#insert-section))

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use a prepared statement? The best way of avoiding conversion problems is to use prepared statements with parameter placeholders and specify the values as parameter values - no string conversions needed (and no worrying about SQL injection attacks).

(If you *really* have to specify the values in the SQL, I'd try using 2-digit month/day values, and a 4-digit year.)

Comment: I tried with 2-digit month/day values and 4-digit year but it is deosn't working.

Comment: @RAVITEJA: And did you try the main thrust of my answer, namely *not* trying to embed the value directly in text in the first place?